# CSS having 2 elements in container: image and text, always display the image after text and cut the text (with ellipsis) if not enough space for both

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a container (with width and height limitation), which has 2 elements inside it : text and info tooltip icon, I need to always display the info icon **after the text and inline with it** - meaning I have maximum width defined for the text to ensure the icon will always end in same line with the text. if the text is longer- I have to cut it with ellipsis. the container can include up to two lines.

I am using React and therefor cant use the text as ::before for the info icon as the content varies and in react there is no way to insert pseudo elements in code:(

I guess I need pure CSS solution - tried with no luck so far...

Some UCs for illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add `text` class (that limit text lines) to Pinkal Patel answer:

```css
.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end">
                <div class="text-justify text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
                </div>
                <div clss="" style="padding-left:10px;">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/info.png" class="" style="height: 30px; width:30px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end">
                <div class="text-justify">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
                </div>
                <div clss="" style="padding-left:10px;">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/info.png" class="" style="height: 30px; width:30px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using Flex Bootstrap CSS code you can build as you can.

Comment: Thanks for answering!, but I stated in my question that text should be up to 2 lines and cut with ellipsis if longer. also that the icon should be right after the texts - as seen in the SS I attached... - It should be implemented with display inline i guess...